# JavaScript SpeechSynthesisUtterance

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Why does the SpeechSynthesisUtterance.volume property return "0.4000000059604645" when set to ".4"?

```js
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
u.volume = .4;
console.log(u.volume);
```

```
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
u.volume = .4;
console.log(u.volume);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.volume` property is specified to be stored [as a "float"](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#dom-speechsynthesisutterance-volume), which [means](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-float) that it's stored per single-precision 32 bit IEEE 754.

If you [plug in](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) 0.4, you get the hex value of 0x3ecccccd, which, when converted back to decimal, is 0.4000000059604645 (due to imprecision).

This is in contrast to normal JavaScript numbers, in which are stored as double-precision 64-bit numbers (and thus have many more accurate trailing digits).

Comment: So what can I do to convert the "u.volume" back to ".4" so that I can store it as ".4" instead of "0.4000000059604645"?

Comment: Just dropping off the digits past the 1st (or 2nd or 3rd, whatever you want) decimal place would be a possible approach.

Comment: So use the toPrecision(1) function?

Comment: If doing that suits your purposes, sure